# How to deal with differences between class and MongoDB document

Tags: c#, mongodb

So i have class like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And lets say that i add some such document to MongoDB.
But, what if i remove some field from my class?
For example i leave only `Id`  and `FirstName`

Then, when i try to recive data in such way:

```
var result = db.Get<Customer>().AsQueryable<Customer>();
```

I have an exception that

### **"Element 'LastName' does not match any field or property of class AKMongo.Customer."**

Of course i understand this, and why this happen, but how to deal with it?

By the way,  my `Get` method just returns

```
    return _database.GetCollection<Customer>("Customer");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add the `BsonIgnoreExtraElements` [attribute](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#ignoring-extra-elements) to your class:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Customer
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

The other is to use the class map:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Customer>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
});
```

Or, you could look into the [catch all](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#supporting-extra-elements) field.